# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'config.forEach') - Angular2 Route Test

Tags: testing, angular, typescript, karma-runner

i'm a complete newbie in Angular2 especially in Testing. I've searched the web for a solution but there is so much old code examples that doesn't work anymore. So I came here to ask you.

When i ran my test with "karma test". I get the following error:

> Error: Error in ./NavbarItemComponent class NavbarItemComponent -
>   inline template:1:1 caused by: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'config.forEach') in config/karma/karma-test-shim.js (line 20623)

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarVerticalComponent } from './navbar-vertical/navbar-vertical.component';
import { NavbarItemComponent } from './navbar-item/navbar-item.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

class MockRouter extends Router {
  navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
  routerState: RouterState;
}

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
    declarations: [AppComponent, NavbarVerticalComponent, NavbarItemComponent ],
    providers: [
      { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter  }
    ],
    imports: [RouterTestingModule]
    });
  });

  it ('should work', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof AppComponent).toBe(true, 'should create AppComponent');
  });

});
```

Comment: Can you show your NavbarItemComponent

Answer (score 0):

I use the router-stubs.ts file from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#router-outlet-component

```
// export for convenience.
export { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink, RouterOutlet} from '@angular/router';

import { Component, Directive, Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()'
  }
})
export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any;
  navigatedTo: any = null;

  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams;
  }
}

@Component({selector: 'router-outlet', template: ''})
export class RouterOutletStubComponent { }

@Injectable()
export class RouterStub {
  navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras) { }
}


// Only implements params and part of snapshot.params
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ActivatedRouteStub {

  // ActivatedRoute.params is Observable
  private subject = new BehaviorSubject(this.testParams);
  params = this.subject.asObservable();

  // Test parameters
  private _testParams: {};
  get testParams() { return this._testParams; }
  set testParams(params: {}) {
    this._testParams = params;
    this.subject.next(params);
  }

  // ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params
  get snapshot() {
    return { params: this.testParams };
  }
}


/*
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

the updated app.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarVerticalComponent } from './navbar-vertical/navbar-vertical.component';
import { NavbarItemComponent } from './navbar-item/navbar-item.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { RouterOutletStubComponent, RouterLinkStubDirective } from './testing/router-stubs';

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({ 
      declarations: [AppComponent, 
                     NavbarVerticalComponent, 
                     NavbarItemComponent,
                     RouterLinkStubDirective,
                     RouterOutletStubComponent]
    });
  });

  it ('should work', () => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(fixture.componentInstance instanceof AppComponent).toBe(true, 'should create AppComponent');
  });

});
```

It works now.

Comment: I know I'm late, but I would like to know where you found this file, i can't seem to reach it with the link you gave.

Comment: You're awesome!